# Swfupload issue, can't use it's method addPostParam

Tags: php, javascript, jakarta-ee, swfupload

I've done my research here, none of them solved my problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var swfu;

    window.onload = function() {
        var settings = {
            //here I ripped out my settings for convenience 
        };

        swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);
        swfu.addPostParam("user_id", "123456789");
     };
</script>
```

Now I got this error: Uncaught Call to SetPostParams failed

In fact I can't call any method, because All of them gets the same error.

What happended here?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Did you check if the SWF was loaded, before calling `addPostParam`? This solved the problem for me.

You can wait for the `swfupload_loaded_handler` event:

```
var settings = {
    // Your settings...
    // More settings...
    // Some more...
    swfupload_loaded_handler: swfUploaderLoaded
}

swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);

function swfUploaderLoaded() {
    // Loaded! Call it now.
    this.addPostParam("user_id", "123456789"); // or swfu.addPostParam()
}
```